# What am I doing wrong? (C)

Tags: c

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong with this. Every time I compile it, at the fourth user input, it just stops and shows the "processes returned" stuff.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

char firstname[15], class, swordch0c1, swordch0c2;
int health, healthtot, armor, armortot;

printf("Hello there! Could I have your first name?\n>");
scanf("%s", firstname);

printf("\n---------------------The Legend of %s---------------------", firstname);
printf("\nPress Enter to continue.");
getch();

printf("\n\n\nYou are %s, a(n): \nA.Swordsman\nB.Assassin\nC.Archer\nD.Mage\n>", firstname);
scanf(" %c", &class);

/*swordsman story starts here*/
if (class=='a' || class=='A')
    {
    printf("\n\nThere you stand, at your boring everyday post.\nWhen you joined the army, you thought it would be more exciting than this.\nJust then, you see your general walking towards you.");
    printf("\n\nYou quickly improve your posture. \"Soldier, I have an opportunity for you\"\nA.\"Really? What is it?\"\nB.\"I'm not interested\"\n>");
    scanf(" %c", &swordch0c1);

    if (swordch0c1=='b'||swordch0c1=='B')
        {
        printf("\n\"But... I didn't even tell you what it was. Okay, suit yourself\" You are DOOMED to a life of boredom.\n\n\n\n\n");
        }

    if (swordch0c1=='a'||swordch0c1=='A')
        {
        printf("\n\n\n\"Well, you see, there's this dragon. He's been causing big problems.\nHe's destroyed villages, harrassed the priests on the mountain,\n");
```

...
edit:It does allow me to put in the fourth input. after hitting enter, it shows the processes returned stuff.

Comment: do you get to enter the fourth input or does it just skip it ?

Comment: You're going to have to show your entire code (or at least up to the point of the "fourth user input").

Comment: @jwodder, that is the code up until the fourth input.

Comment: `printf` the value of `swordch0c1` after the input because it's probably not 'b' nor 'a'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is almost definitely the problem:

```
scanf(" %c", &swordch0c1);
```

You are asking to read a single character, however to actually enter a character you have to type two characters: <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. This `scanf` call will read the `'A'`, and the next `scanf` call will read the `'\n'` (the <kbd>Enter</kbd>) key, which is still in the input buffer.

I suggest using `fgets()` for all user input. It's a lot easier to deal with that way, because it matches the way users actually enter input (line of text plus <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have an idea on why the user input before it worked with that format?

Comment: The space at the front (`" %c"`) will cause `scanf` to skip over whitespace in the input buffer (the Enter keypress is whitespace). You haven't shown your fourth user input, so I'm not sure what it says.